# html css jquery modal doesn't open in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a modal window when a button is clicked for registering users.I don't know what is wrong. The button gets clicked but modal window doesn't open. My code is like this

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById(mymodal).style.display='block';">Create</button>


  <div id="mymodal" class="ourmodal">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
.ourmodal{
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  overflow:auto;
  z-index:1;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:grey;
}
.modal-content{
  background-color:honeydew;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add single quotes:

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('mymodal').style.display='block'">....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery if you have inserted it.

You can simple give an ID to the button and then use the follwoing code:

```
 <div class="button">
      <button type="button" id="open-modal" ">Create</button>


      <div id="mymodal" class="ourmodal">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <button id="close-modal">close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and write the script after the jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script>
        jQuery('#open-modal').on('click',function(){
            jQuery('#mymodal').show();
        });
        jQuery('#close-modal').on('click',function(){
            jQuery('#mymodal').hide();
        });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@ram-kc

Please try this code :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodal">Create</button>


  <div id="mymodal" class="ourmodal">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
.ourmodal{
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  overflow:auto;
  z-index:1;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:grey;
}
.modal-content{
  background-color:honeydew;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}
</style>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.
Thank you.